# Filemaker and Google Calendar. How do I make them communicate?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, filemaker

I am somewhat new to programming, have some experience with VBA, but thats it. I am learning Filemaker at the moment and I am getting along quite nicely. I want to let FM automaticly enter certain appointments and reminders into my google calendar.

Now, I know that the calendar has an API, and I know that that API is the interface with which I can communicate with it. But I am lacking a step in my knowledge ladder, because the documentation is thoroughly confusing. I need to know what to use, in order to tell the calendar what to enter where. Is it like some compound url I construct? How do I login?

These are all questions that pop up. I don't expect you to answer those, but rather if you can point me to the right tutorials I can read to get this knowledge.

I hope I didn't burden you guys too much.

thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the authors of [Zulu](http://360works.com/zulu/), a product we built specifically to sync FileMaker to Google Calendar, using a bi-directional sync. You can also turn Zulu into your own CalDAV server if you want to go that route.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you. But I want to learn stuff on my own. I understand that that is your livelyhood, but I want to avoid paying for add-ins at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't take this wrong but you may be biting off too much. I have been programming for 30 years and it took me a couple of days to gather the information needed to interact with the Google APIs (the OAuth2 authentication can be really confusing at first).

My sugestion would be to look at importing calendars into Google Calendars using either CSV (https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45656) or ICS (https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45656) format. You should be able to generate those formats with a little bit of Filemaker scripting.

But since you asked:

- You need the OAUTH2 offline access, with a refresh token you would
  store somewhere.
- You will use the refresh token to get an auth token
- You will make requests using HTTPS GETS or POSTS (see the [Calendar
  API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/)), with the auth token in the Authorization header.
  Since there is no Google Calendar API for FileMaker :-), you would
  have to know some details of the HTTP protocol to send a properly
  formatted request, you will be working at a lower level than you
  would be if using a Python, Java or .NET library.
- You will get back
  JSON responses which you will have to parse.

Comment: Oh, I'm fully aware that I might be biting off too much! Its just that I want to learn, and I want to get to know how to interact with API's in general. But thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can try to do this quickly:

- Use Zapier (http://zpr.io/VhK - affiliate link) to create a webhook, then use a hidden webviewer in FileMaker to create the event. Try this as an example: http://zpr.io/fqg7
- Use a plug-in, like this one https://www.feedzon.com/products/fmgcal/. I've never used that particular one before, but it looks fairly straightforward.

If you want to go whole-hog, it is also possible to use scripts in FileMaker to write to the Google Calendar API, but it's a lot more work. The plugin is probably the easiest route to go.

If you don't want to use a plugin, I would recommend starting with a Zapier webhook, as it greatly simplifies the work needed to hook into the Google Calendar API.